# Using Javascript to pull data from an RSS Atom feed

Tags: javascript, html, xml, rss, atom-feed

I have written a webpage that takes in an XML file from an RSS and parses it by certain tags. I have tested it on a local copy of the data I am planning on using and it works fine. The catch is that I cannot figure out how to call an RSS file on a different webpage and parse its data.

Here is my code for setting up the parser:

```js
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", ".../NewsFeed.aspx?output=Atom", false);
```

Here is the header of the xml file I get when I inspect the RSS page:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<feed xml:lang="en-us" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<title type="text"> News</title>
<subtitle type="text">A syndication of the most recently published news.</subtitle>

<id>uuid:64d61c8e-c5d7-4529-b5a3-2dcd4097238b;id=50</id>

<rights type="text">© 2013 <owner goes here>. All Rights Reserved.</rights>

<updated>2013-07-09T13:34:27Z</updated>

<link rel="alternate" href=".../Default.aspx" />
<link rel="self" href=".../NewsFeed.aspx" />
```

I edited the links for posting purposes. I have tried using both of the links listed in the RSS document as well as the URL to the external feed in the open xml method, but I had no luck.

```js
 xmlhttp.open("GET", "link goes here", false);
```

Does anyone know how I would read the RSS feed? As a side note, the feed is a standard RSS feed (2.0) returned in Atom format.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by either of those. I am not very familiar with the interaction of HTML/JS and XML

Comment: when someone gives me a suggestion i've not heard of, the first thing i do is google it...

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check for starters:

1) Your NewsFeed.aspx needs to be hosted at exactly the same protocol, sub-domain, domain, and port as the page calling it. Otherwise browser security kicks in and prevents you from using an XHR. If you're trying to read a 3rd party RSS feed you may need to use a proxy.

2) The content-type header of the response needs to be text/xml. There are ways to get around this, but it's better if the content-type is accurate.

Comment: In response to your first point, that is probably why it doesn't work. I am developing on a sandbox server and the RSS is on live.

As for the second,  I am not in control of how the XML/RSS is formatted so I have to work within its constraints

Comment: Sounds like you need a proxy, I've had to do the same thing myself. Regarding the content-type, note it's a response header NOT part of the XML formatting. Response headers are set by the server, so if you get to a point where you can see it's incorrect, you'll have to talk to the server admin.

Comment: You can also use Superfeedr's API with supports JSONP on feed retriveal :)